# Showing $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]=(0,1]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $$\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]=(0,1].$$
I have done with $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]\subseteq (0,1].$
Then, how to show that $(0,1]\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]$?
I tried to use contraposition by taking $x\notin  \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]$, it means that $x\in (-\infty,\frac{1}{n+1})\cup (\frac{1}{n},\infty)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. However, there exists $1+\frac{1}{n}\in (-\infty,\frac{1}{n+1})\cup (\frac{1}{n},\infty)$ but $1+\frac{1}{n}\notin (0,1]$, therefore $(-\infty,\frac{1}{n+1})\cup (\frac{1}{n},\infty)\nsubseteq (0,1]$. Thus, $x\notin (0,1]$. 
But, I am not sure with my attempt. Is it correct?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your contrapositive proof does not work: you start with a generic $x\notin\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \big[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\big]$, and you need to show that $x\notin(0,1]$. You cannot specific $x$ to be equal to a specific value ($1+\frac{1}{n}$)

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall x\in (0,1], \frac{1}x\ge 1, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}, n\le \frac{1}x\le n+1\Rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1}\le x\le \frac{1}n\Rightarrow x\in\left[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}n \right]$$

Comment: Well, this is definitely not a proof. It doesn't have a single word in it.